# Wordpress Pagination on posts page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am really struggling to find out where or how to introduce paginate to my wordpess post page...

```
<?php
    if (is_tag()) {
        $args = array('tag_id' => get_queried_object_id());
    } else {
        $args = array('cat' => get_queried_object_id());
    }

    $i=1;
    $latest_blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args  );

    if ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $latest_blog_posts->the_post();

    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        $cat_name = $category->cat_name;
        $cat_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
    }

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 2600,1000 ), false, '' );
?> 

<div style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;">   
        <div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ); width: 330px; height: 260px; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; width: 600px;"> 
        <h2 style="margin:0; padding: 0;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><span style="font-weight: 200; color: #aaa;">| <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></span></p>
        <p style="line-height: 160%;"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,500); ?> [...]</p>

        <?php echo get_the_tag_list('<p> | ','&nbsp;&nbsp; | ','</p>'); ?>
        <?php $archive_year = get_the_time('Y'); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; endwhile; endif;    ?>
```

The file is specifically named category-blog.php

I am not sure where in the script I need to be adding in the pagination, I have tried to understand from where in the codex the examples tie into how I am utilising my content.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you, i use this code, add it to functions.php

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {



  function wpex_pagination() {



      $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;';

      $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;';



      global $wp_query;

      $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

      $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

      if( $total > 0 )  {

           if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )

               $current_page = 1;

           if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {

               $format = 'page/%#%/';

           } else {

               $format = '&paged=%#%';

           }

          echo paginate_links(array(

              'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

              'format'        => $format,

              'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

              'total'         => $total,

              'mid_size'      => 3,

              'type'          => 'list',

              'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,

              'next_text'     => $next_arrow,

           ) );

      }

  }



}
```

You can use it in your category-blog.php like:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php wpex_pagination(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I appear to be getting a syntax error placing that content into my functions file...

Comment: hm there are no syntaxerrors in code, be sure to not paste into any if else or function...you may paste it at the very end of file before `?>`closing php tag

Comment: so strange, I missed a closing tag. However no syntax errors now but when I place in the div nothing shows, is there a specific place in my above code I need put this?

Comment: I have added a background color to it and it shows the div is there but there is nothing showing within the div at all

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the paged parameter to your args array. The `paged` variable is retrieved from the page query var which you can get like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

You would then probably want to limit the number of posts per page using the `posts_per_page` parameter. So your args array would be something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
```

Wordpress has a built in function to display pagination links that quite well out the box called `paginate_links` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links.

Comment: I am really struggling to to find where to place in my above code where this will go because I have managed to get it to before but since removed because it isnt really working correctly, by this I mean it shows pages 1 & 2 but if you click the link to go to page 2 it fails to show any posts and freaks out...

Comment: I have added the arg in and its working fine, so it only displays how many posts I want. I am just now unable to bring in the pagination.

Comment: Are you using the paginate_links function?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I fixed it...

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

if (is_tag()) {
$args = array(
'tag_id' => get_queried_object_id(),
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'paged' => $paged
);

} else {
$args = array(
'cat' => get_queried_object_id(),
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'paged' => $paged
);

}

$i=1;

$latest_blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args  );

if ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $latest_blog_posts->the_post();



foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
   $cat_name = $category->cat_name;
   $cat_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
}

$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 2600,1000 ), false, '' );

?>


 <?php endif; ?>


<div style="height: auto; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 20px;">

    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;">   

        <div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ); width: 330px; height: 260px; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>

    </div>

        <div style="float: right; width: 600px;"> 

            <h2 style="margin:0; padding: 0;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <p><span style="font-weight: 200; color: #aaa;">| <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></span></p>

                    <p style="line-height: 160%;"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,500); ?> [...]</p>

                    <?php echo get_the_tag_list('<p> | ','&nbsp;&nbsp; | ','</p>'); ?>

                    <?php $archive_year = get_the_time('Y'); ?>

        </div>

</div>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php $i++; endwhile; endif;    ?> 

<?php


$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $latest_blog_posts->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

Also in the wp-admins etting I set under 'reading' the 'Blog pages show at most' and set it to 4 to reflect the above, hey presto it appeared!